# What causes extremely small p values in Granger causality test?

Tags: p-value, granger-causality

I am generating some Granger causality tests for various time-series. I have noticed something that appears odd. I have timeseries $A$ and $B$. Sample size is about 1500 elements in each.

$A$ and $B$ are highly correlated about 70%.

When I do a 1 ,2,or 3 lag Granger test I get p values like 0.0000000000034.

That seems way too low - I would be happy if it was around 0.01.

Is there something else I need to take into account?

Answer (score 3):

It is not clear what you mean by A & B are highly correlated.  Is it that the cross-correlation at lag zero is 0.7?  If that is the case it could be that the p-value is so small because you have a long series of length 1500 and the individual series have a relatively small residual variance from the model. So it is easy to detect the high cross-correlation between the series.  Also the test probably assumes normally distributed residuals which assuming a sharply decreasing structure to the tails of the error distribution.

Comment: yes the 0.7 cor is as you state. But such a low value suggests that B g-cause A. My p values for A g-cause B are much higher around 0.3. I am just worried because it seems so positive a result. Is something in the way I have set it up making it overally "rosy"?

Comment: The p-value depends heavily on the tail behavior of the assumed distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis.  The observed p-value depends havily on normality.  Perhaps normality is incorrect.  A distribution with heavier tail behavior could have a much larger (relatively) value than the value of  0.0000000000034 that you got.  I never take such p-values very seriously.  It really is just an indication that the result is highly significant.

Comment: Thanks. Does the R2 value - or Ftest number add information. Or is the p value the whole story?

Comment: You are comparing correlated Xi to the Yis. So the R square and F tests in a linear regression don't really apply here. The Granger test on the other hand takes the time series structure into account.